# Communicate two webview

Tags: android-webview

I'm locally storing my two webviews(html file). and I displayed two webview in same activity.
I trying to communicate two webviews.e.g.:

**Webview1:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="displayInSecondWebview()" value="Click Here"/>
```

**Webview 2:**

```
function displayInSecondWebview(){
//code to display
}
```

Two webview(html file) has same javascript file. But it's doesn't work. Is there ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) was designed for doing this.